# Skip Undefined Error if an object key is missing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I would like to know as to how can we skip Undefined error being throw if a key is missing.

```
[
  {
    "id": "foo1",
    "name": "Test1",
    "description": "random test1",
    "languages": [
      "en"
    ],
    "subThemes": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Bike"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Testy",
        "description": "Testing this thing1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "foo2",
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "random test2",
    "languages": [
      "en"
    ],
    "subThemes": [
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Bike2"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Testy2",
        "description": "Testing this thing2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "foo3",
    "name": "Test3",
    "description": "random test3",
    "languages": [
      "en"
    ]
  }
]
```

Let say I have an array object like this above, If I do a map over it, it is giving me an error because I don't have a subThemes key in the 3rd object.

```
const children = theme.subThemes
      .map(subTheme => {
        const { subThemes = [] } = aggregations;  
              ...rest of the code}

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

How do I bypass the undefined error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your code and error

Comment: can you show how you implemented it with the map function?

Comment: Added the code snipped @user969068

Comment: You may use conditional chaining (`theme.subThemes?.map(..`)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Throw Syntax error:  Unexpected token

Comment: @AdityaShukla : do you happen to use typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how is that sounds?

```
if ( Array.isArray(myJson.languages))
     myJson.languages.map(.....
```

or for returning empty array (ES6 syntax)

```
(myJson.languages || []).map(x => { .... });
```

or for returning undefined without having error (ES6 syntax)

```
myJson.languages?.map(x => { ... });
```